# Adding `**` to head of lines with numbers in the beginning

Tags: regular-expressions

I have the following contexts:

```
4. Pattern-Matching Conditional: How to use pcase and friends.
5. Iteration: while loops.
6. Generators: Generic sequences and coroutines.
```

and intent add `**` to the head of each lines thus try replace-regexp
`^\([::digit::]\) → ** \1`
However, nothing happened.

What's the problem with my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character class name should be enclosed between `[:` and `:]`[(see emacs manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html), the correct pattern is

```
^\([[:digit:]]\)
```

Since you have a single group you can skip the parentheses and refer to the whole match with `\&`, e.g:

```
^[[:digit:]] → ** \&
```